# $http.get requests in Angular doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Forgive me, but I'm newbie in Angular. I've got a problem with $http requests in AngularJS. What am I doing wrong? Almost as in tutorial, but data still aren't fetch.

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);
app.controller('TestController', [$http, TestController]);

function TestController($http) {
    var store = this;
    store.personalInfo = [];

    $http.get('/data.json')
    .success(function(data){
        store.personalInfo = data;
    })
    .error(function(){
        store.personalInfo = "Error occured";
    });
}
```

And here is my view:

```
<body ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="TestController as test">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <p ng-repeat="item in test.personalInfo">
        {{ item.firstName }}
    </p>

    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.25" data-semver="1.2.25" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you receive an error in your console?Try to use breakpoint to trace where did you got a problem..

Answer (score 0):

You must use Injection with quotes, change this:

```
app.controller('TestController', [$http, TestController]);
```

By this:

```
app.controller('TestController', ['$http', TestController]);
```